# vb.net create sqlcommand module

Tags: vb.net

I've a question:
how can I create a module with function for insert into sql database and use it in many forms passing a dynamic parameter?
I know how build module, but I don't know how passing the parameter while call this module in a form.
Ex. build module insert into loggging table with timestamp, username and action while clicking save button in many forms and where action change.
Thanks advance.

Comment: Consider a class to do that...you set some properties and/or pass some text and it does the insert for you

Comment: MS SQL or MySQL. I can supply you a class already made that you can add different functions to it.

Comment: MS SQL. I've create many mdules with SQL query, but I don't know how reuse a function dynamically changing parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
Public Class Data

    Private ReadOnly Property ConnectionString As String = "Connection String Here"

    Public Sub InsertLog(ByVal UserName As String, ByVal LogAction As String)
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString), _
              cmd As New Sqlcommand("INSERT INTO LOG VALUES (current_timestamp, @UserName, @Action)"

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = UserName
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Action", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000).Value = LogAction

            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

Remember, this is just an example. There are many variants. The important things in here are using parameterized queries rather than string concatenation, and NOT trying to re-use the same connection object throughout the application (this trips up a lot of people because it messes with the connection pooling in the ADO.Net driver).

Comment: Joel Coehoom can you give me a URL where I can read more about not reusing a connection object? When I read about ADO.net connection pooling it seems to depend on .Open and .Close not object creation. I am sure you are correct. I am just curious.

Comment: I'll try, but parameter logaction can be defined into button click handles variabile?